# Change color of Cells based on another cell´s value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

In this vba:

```
Sub color()
Dim color As Integer
For Each cell In Sheets(6).Range("F2:F65536")
If IsEmpty(cell) Then GoTo nextcell:
If Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then GoTo nextcell:
If cell.Value > 50 Then
  color = 4
ElseIf cell.Value < 35 Then color = 3
Else: color = 2
End If
cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = color
nextcell:
Next cell
End Sub
```

What do you change to change colors in cells B3:F3 and so on B4:F4, etc. instead of entire row?

Comment: Is the excel conditional formatting out of question?

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways -

```
ElseIf cell.Value < 35 Then color = 3
Else: color = 2
End If
Range(cells(cell.row,2),cells(cell.row,6)).interior.color = rgb(color)
```

That should work. Otherwise -

```
Range("B" & cell.row & ":F" & cell.row).interior.color = rgb(color)
```

Other than that you could do something like

```
range(cell.offset(,-4),cell).interior.color = rgb(color)
```

But I wouldn't do that.

Comment: If you're problem is solved, be sure to check the green checkmark next to the answer to indicate [it's been solved](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer)